# How is text value stored in Excel cell that references an xla add-in function?

Tags: excel, xlsx, openpyxl, xla

I have an xlsx file that I am trying to parse and one of the cells references an xla add-in function.

```
='C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\Query and Analysis\LsAgXLB.xla'!AG_SMRT("0,Summary Report 1,1")
```

That file does not exist on my local machine but likely existed on the person's who created the file.

However, looking at the cell in Excel, it does display a text value 'CTP116701'.  But the actual value of the cell is the xla function.  Where and how is it pulling the 'CTP116701' value?

I'm trying to use Python and openpyxl to parse the spreadsheet.

Comment: Could that be the value placed there by the add-in UDF?

Comment: I have to assume it was but the add-in and xla file certainly do not exist on my machine.  I see nothing under the ADD-INS tab.  My knowledge of the workings of Excel is very limited.

Comment: In general, if a link is not present when a worksheet is opened, the last computed "value" will be displayed.  Excel stores both that value and the link.  I haven't checked to see if this occurs when the result is coming from a formula that is stored in an add-in, but I would think the same rules apply.

Comment: If you want to explore this further, and you are using an xlsm file, change the file extension to .zip.  Then open it and look at the worksheet and cell, and follow the references around.  You will see that both the last computed "value" as well as the base "formula" can be derived from what is in there. Also, in the worksheet, if you try to update that value, you will probably get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the .zip extension - it led me to the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pull the previously computed and stored value of the cell by opening the workbook in data_only mode:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
```

While investigating, I did change the file extension to .zip and found the worksheet xml file.  This was helpful because I could see that the 'CTP116701' value was indeed stored in the cell along with the function string.